# Improvements suggestions

Tags: development, webapp-development

If I would like to email Ubuntu for improvement suggestions of the entire operating system.
Who do I email?

Or where can I find the real support site for Ubuntu like.
Support ticket.intel.com similar at Ubuntu?.

- As well Ubuntu / Debian needs to make feedback hub like Microsoft
- An Application inside of the operating system itself when you brand new install Ubuntu
- An application you login into with username and password or OTP code from email
- Be able to set this in Feedback hub assistant Settings that also needs to be coded

The application itself needs to be

0.0 The version/name of the os that has the issue
0.0.1 The version/name of an app or software that has an issue
1.0 Headline
1.1 Issue or suggestion summary
1.2 Issue or suggestion explained in detail
1.3 Issue or suggestion category
1.4 Issue Type Problem or suggestion
1.5 Issue Severity] [minor or major]
1.6 [Upload functionality]
1.6.1 Upload from storage or photo album / video album of attachment
1.6.2 It should be able to upload the most common .txt format like .txt/.md, etc.
1.6.3 It should be able to upload the most common . video format. mpg4 and .avi
1.6.4 Input field for mail and contact address that should be anonymous presented
when the Error/Issue/problem ticket has been send from the Help Feedback form.
1.6.5 Cancel or Send button

All of this above to make more people send in error/issues and suggestion improvements of the operating system to the Ubuntu Support Department and easier for Ubuntu to keep track of errors and issues and faster be able to solve them with the Development and testing recycling of work.

Who can speak more to for Ubuntu to build a Feedback hub for inside of the operating system?

If there are any question please email me at atechonea@outlook.com

Comment: I think you're missing the spirit of Ask Ubuntu, and Stack Exchange in general.  Additionally, although different opinions are appreciated and we should be open to discussion, I must say most Linux users do not want to make Linux "more like Microsoft" in any means.  You're free to disagree and create the software though.

Comment: feel free to make it yourself,  2FA login is already possible "As well Ubuntu / Debian needs to make feedback hub like Microsoft" why? we have discourse: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a technical question about Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a user support site (a Q&A site). If you have *feature requests* for applications or systems you can file bug reports against the package & just make it clear it's a feature request. Ubuntu uses launchpad as its bug tracker, though you can also file upstream at github etc too. Some discussions take place at the *Ubuntu Community Hub* too, with occasional requests for feedback etc (less format than feature requests on bug reports) but details vary on Ubuntu Core, Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server etc & you don't mention specific product(s) just the overall project name (too broad)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu developers already receive far more "suggestions for improvement" than they can possibly implement.

From 2008-2012, Ubuntu did indeed try a system for suggesting improvements (Ubuntu Brainstorm). Unfortunately, most suggestions turned out to be junk. Most "suggesters" were unwilling to help implement their visions. Most wanted "someone else" to create software or do other unpaid work for them. For free. Others wanted to simply complain. We kept it up for four long years, a great experiment.

That's not how Free and Open Source Software works, of course. You are not a *customer* and Ubuntu is not your *vendor*. You are a participant. You can participate lots of helpful ways like contributing new features or reporting bugs or writing documentation. There is a lot you can do to help.

Generally, try to avoid the following unhelpful suggestions:

- Fix my bug
- Develop this application for me
- Let’s change the default behavior for everybody
- Complaints
- This killer app will make Ubuntu spectacularly popular

Comment: If only Ubuntu themselves had followed #3!